# Tornado is "a relatively simple, non-blocking web server framework written in Python"--can somewhat explain what that means?

Tags: apache2, twisted, tornado

This is probably a stupid question, but what exactly is a "non-blocking web server"? All web servers are technically non-blocking, arent they? otherwise how could they handle simultaneous connections? Apache2 achieves this using a combination of fork() and pthreads. How exactly are Tornado (and Twisted also) different? Do they just set a bunch of sockets to non-bocking mode, build an FD list (or equivalent), and then loop over that with one big select() sys call?

Where would you use a framework like these, and what advantages can they give you over Apache2 (or other popular servers)? Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This [article on EventMachine](http://www.igvita.com/2008/05/27/ruby-eventmachine-the-speed-demon/) may also give you a hint:

> Steeped in the tradition of forking /
>   threaded web-servers I found myself
>   rather surprised when I joined one of
>   the research projects at University of
>   Waterloo a couple of years back: we
>   were benchmarking different web-server
>   architectures, and top performers were
>   all event-driven servers.
>
> As I pestered everyone with questions,
>   I quickly realized why - in an
>   environment with hundreds of thousands
>   requests a second, forking and context
>   switching associated with thread
>   management become prohibitively
>   expensive (fork is worst performer, as
>   it does a memory copy on the parent
>   process every time). Whereas by
>   comparison, a tight and highly
>   optimized event-loop really shines
>   when it comes to performance under
>   heavy loads.

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering what was so remarkable about an event-loop select()/epoll() architecture (something I read about yeaaaars ago in a TCP book), and why it might be better than threads.